# can the key of the object be a numeric value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On the nodejs terminal the following object **a** is created which contains both numeric and non-numeric keys.

The value of the non-numeric keys can be accessed  using the syntax **a.**. Where as the value of the numeric key can not be accessed with the same syntax.

```
$ node
> a = { 2: 'val1', 3: 'val2', 4: 'val3', obj: 'val4' }
{ '2': 'val1',
  '3': 'val2',
  '4': 'val3',
  obj: 'val4' }
> a.obj
'val4'
> a.'2' # cannot access the value
...
> a.2
...
...
```

Why is this a limitation? Is it okay to create objects with numeric keys?

Comment: It's just that syntactically you cannot access a numeric property by saying `object.1`, you have to say `object[1]`.

Comment: if you have only numeric keys, and they happen to be in order, you should use an array so that you get lots of free extras on your data structure.

Comment: A JSON is an associative array.

Comment: All property names on an object are strings.  If you assign `x[1] = "foo"`, it converts the `1` to `"1"` and uses `"1"` as the actual property name.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/meqecezj/.  Numeric looking property names must be accessed with the `obj[3]` syntax because you can't do `obj.3`.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation is because the dot notation follows the same naming rules as normal variables.

You can use square brackets to access all fields:

```
var a = {foo: 'bar', 5: 'bar2'};
alert(a[5]); //bar2
alert(a['foo']); //bar
```

Comment: Property names are not actually numbers.  If you try to use a numeric property name, Javascript converts it to a string and uses the string representation of the number as the actual property name.

Comment: yep, and that's why it's allowed with brackets